# Can I stay in Mexico with C1/D visa?

Tags: visas, mexico, serbia, serbian-citizens

I work on a ship and I will disembark in Cozumel, Mexico.

Can I stay for a vacation in Mexico with my C1/D visa?

I hold a Serbian passport.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can go to Mexico on a C1/D visa.

The [Mexican consulate](https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/sanfrancisco/index.php/visas-traveling-to-mexico) states:

> all those foreign nationals, regardless of their nationality, visiting Mexico for tourism, business or transit are NOT required to obtain a Mexican visa **IF they hold a valid (non-expired) Visa or Permanent Residence of United States of America**